# linearization topological sorting which repeatedly removes source nodes from the graph

Tags: algorithms, topological-graph-theory

The chapter suggests an alternative algorithm for linearization (topological sorting), which repeatedly removes source nodes from the graph (page 101). Show that this algorithm can be
implemented in linear time.

solution:

> #### Another algorithm for topological sorting.
>
> We will keep an array $\mathbf {in}[u]$ which holds the indegree (number of incoming edges) of each node. For a source, this value is zero. We will also keep a linked list of source nodes.
>
> (Set the $\mathbf{in}$ array.)
>   for all $u\in V$: $\mathbf{in}[u]\gets 0$
>   for all edges $(u,w)\in E$: $\mathbf{in}[w]\gets \mathbf{in}[w]+1$
>
> (Check for sources.)
>   $L\gets \text{empty linked list}$
>   for all $u\in V$:
>     if $\mathbf{in}[u]$ is $0$: add $u$ to $L$
>
> for $i=1 \text{ to } |V|$:
>     Let $u$ be the first node on $L$; output it and remove it from $L$.
>     (Remove $u$; update indegrees.)
>     for each edge $(u,w)\in E$:
>       $\mathbf{in}[w]\gets \mathbf{in}-1$
>       if $\mathbf{in}[w]$ is $0$: add $w$ to $L$.

I understand it until the last part. Can someone go over the "for $i=1 \text{ to } |V|$" block of the solution?

Comment: idk mathJax, also how did you embed the jpeg, i can just do that next time

Comment: You can embed images of graphs, drawings, sculptures, etc. by typing `![alt text here](URL here)`. However, we ask that you type your mathematics using MathJax, as described [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and especially in the links toward the end of that page. Using MathJax rather than images when possible is especially important to allow blind people to use the site.

Comment: The statement `for $i=1$ to $|V|$` means that `repeat until the graph is empty`. You have $|V|$ vertices to remove.